# Looking for image in android.R.drawable

Tags: android, image, drawable

I'm looking for a system-wide graphic that (I think) is in android.R.drawable. I am looking for this one:

[image: Android Graphic]

I realize that graphics differ between systems, however I am fairy sure that it is system wide because I have seen it in multiple programs.

I want to use the one Android provides so that my app looks good no matter what phone it runs on. Does anyone know where I can find that image to use in my program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking a look at [**Android R Drawables**](http://androiddrawables.com/Other.html), it seems it might be `expander_ic_minimized.9`

Answer (score 6):

You can find those images in the Android SDK directory under

platforms/android-X/data/res/drawable-Ydpi

where X is the version code of Android and Y is the resolution (l/m/h). Most images are in the mdpi folder.

It is recommended to copy the images to your App, as the Android developers do not guarantee that all images will be there in future releases.

The image you are looking for looks like

expander_ic_minimized.9.png